# CKEDITOR - Pasted Arabic or Vietnamese Shows with ? Between Characters

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, ckeditor

I've got a CKEDITOR 4 setup that's been working fine, until a user mentioned that pasting Vietnamese or Arabic characters into the editor is causing problems.

My program takes the input and stores it into a SQL Server table, then displays it. They've done several other languages, and only the Arabic and Vietnamese are causing problems. When it's inserted and then being displayed, it has several question marks within the text. I confirmed it was inserted into the table this way from the editor.

An example would be: ???c cung c?p mi?n phí và ch? là d?ch v? t? ph?c v?.

I saw something about making sure UTF-8 encoding was set, which I've done. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to check which character set collation yoir table or colimn has and the ser the connection stirng to the saem character set collation

Comment: Hmm, the collation for that table is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Would that be part of the problem, do those languages require UTF-8?

Comment: Is the column data type varchar? It needs to be nvarchar to store Unicode characters with that collation.

Comment: It is varchar actually...I didn't even think of that. So I need to switch my data type on that column.

Comment: latin1 is no utf8 which you need. but that is difficult as you need to connect to the first tabe with latin1 and a second with uf8 and transfer the data.

Comment: Hmm ok great, I guess I'll get with the DB admin and see if he can do that. Thanks for the advice!